# What does 'precision level' mean in this WMI method?

Tags: c#, wmi, precision, bitlocker

I have an app that needs to run the *GetConversionStatus* method of the *Win32_EncryptableVolume* class in WMI to detect various information about the state of Bitlocker on the current machine.

The [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376433(v=vs.85).aspx) for this method defines a parameter named 'PrecisionFactor'. They describe this as:

> A value from 0 to 4 that specifies the precision level

What is this for? Does anyone know what this actually affects or what difference this has on the output? Is there an English description of what this parameter actually does?

Comment: My first guess would be that it affects the precision of the returned percentage. Care to test it out?

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis yeah I sure can if nobody on here knows for sure. I was hoping for a more conclusive answer rather than relying on what it *appears* to do when I run it.

Answer (score 1):

The percentages are returned always as UInt32. So, to give the users the flexibility of the decimal digits, the `PrecisionFactor` is taken as input.

Based on the precision factor, **the percentages accurate to those many decimal digits would be returned but as UInt32**. The following script explains the behavior:

```
PS C:\> 0..4 | % { $encVol.GetConversionStatus($_).EncryptionPercentage } | ft
```

For my fully encrypted volume, the outputs were

```
100
1000
10000
100000
1000000
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend pinging them via MSDN forum directly.  I dug through old references and it looks like they may have dropped documentation somewhere.

Comment: Care to enlighten us on what the old references say that is different?

Comment: Sure, from when I was working there I remember it had a mapping kind of like http://wutils.com/wmi/root/cimv2/win32_volume/ -> ChkDsk method. Where the value determined at was target end configuration it was going to be in.

Comment: Thanks, I've asked the question here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/fafe1e7c-2d66-4988-af4c-3b901d723e4d